# Is there actually any World-Building stack-exchange-merchandise or was when it was stated more of a hypothetical statement?

Tags: support

On the post for the worldbuilding stack exchange background, there was a snippet about potential merchandise

> Swag

[image]

> Worldbuilding poster, t-shirt, and coffee mug

Is there anywhere to actually buy the merchandise shown above or was the statement more of a hypothetical one? Just curious. Sorry for this being brief, but I couldn't find any other questions which answerd it so here I am.

Comment: I am not aware of any merchandise for the general public, but I also never looked in depth into it.

Comment: To quote a user in chat: "there is [non-site-specific](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358195/swag-is-coming-back) swag for high-rep users and mods, but no [store](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137580)"